# np.linalg.eig gives different eigenvectors for the same matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

The following is based on Python 3.7.6.

I am trying to use a package called PySCF for simple computational chemistry problems. One of the calculations involves the evaluation of a 2D array called the Fock matrix. PySCF generates this using the function get_fock() [[1](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/scf.html), [2](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/_modules/pyscf/scf/hf.html)]. For one of my test cases, the Fock matrix evaluates to

```
F = [[ 2. -1.  0.  0.  0. -1.]
 [-1.  2. -1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  2. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  2. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -1.  2. -1.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  2.]]
```

I tried to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this matrix using `energies, C = np.linalg.eig(F)`, which gives the following matrix of eigenvectors:

```
C = [[-0.40824829  0.57735027  0.40824829  0.57735027  0.2468088   0.08939109]
 [ 0.40824829 -0.28867513  0.40824829  0.28867513 -0.57541553 -0.44927503]
 [-0.40824829 -0.28867513  0.40824829 -0.28867513  0.32860673 -0.53866612]
 [ 0.40824829  0.57735027  0.40824829 -0.57735027  0.2468088  -0.08939109]
 [-0.40824829 -0.28867513  0.40824829 -0.28867513 -0.57541553  0.44927503]
 [ 0.40824829 -0.28867513  0.40824829  0.28867513  0.32860673  0.53866612]]
```

However, `np.matmul(np.matmul(C.T,F),C)` should then return a diagonal matrix whose elements are the eigenvalues of `F`. This is not what happens, but I should note that the **correct eigenvalues** (verified separately) of `F` are indeed stored in `energies`.

I then assigned another matrix `F0` exactly the same elements as `F` (this time, hard-coded into the script). In this case, `np.linalg.eig(F0)` actually gave me a different eigenvector matrix:

```
C0 = [[ 0.23192061  0.41790651 -0.52112089 -0.23192061  0.52112089 -0.41790651]
 [-0.41790651 -0.52112089  0.23192061 -0.41790651  0.23192061 -0.52112089]
 [ 0.52112089  0.23192061  0.41790651 -0.52112089 -0.41790651 -0.23192061]
 [-0.52112089  0.23192061 -0.41790651 -0.52112089 -0.41790651  0.23192061]
 [ 0.41790651 -0.52112089 -0.23192061 -0.41790651  0.23192061  0.52112089]
 [-0.23192061  0.41790651  0.52112089 -0.23192061  0.52112089  0.41790651]]
```

To make sure I'm not insane, I checked the `type` of `F` and `F0`: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` in both cases. I also printed out `F-F0` which is just a 0-matrix as expected. I have pasted my script below, which is an adaptation of one of the PySCF example scripts [[3](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/advanced.html#customizing-hamiltonian)].

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros, matrix
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc, tools

hubbard_U = 2.
hubbard_t = 1.

mol = gto.M(verbose=4)
n = n_basis = 6
mol.nelectron = 12
mol.verbose = 9
mol.incore_anyway = True

h1 = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n-1):
    h1[i,i+1] = h1[i+1,i] = -hubbard_t # -ve Hubbard t
h1[n-1,0] = h1[0,n-1] = -hubbard_t # periodicity

eri = np.zeros((n,n,n,n))
for i in range(n):
    eri[i,i,i,i] = hubbard_U # Hubbard U

mf = scf.RHF(mol)
mf.conv_tol = 1e-8
mf.get_hcore = lambda *args: h1
mf.get_ovlp = lambda *args: np.eye(n)
mf._eri = ao2mo.restore(8, eri, n)
mf.kernel(np.ones((n, n)))

F = np.copy(mf.get_fock())

print('F =')
print(F)
energies, C = np.linalg.eig(F)
print('\nC =', C)
F0 = [[2., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [-1., 2., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0., -1., 2., -1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0., -1., 2., -1.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1., 2., -1.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., 2.]]
print('\nF - F0 =', F-F0)

energies0, C0 = np.linalg.eig(F0)
print('\nC0 =', C0)
```

How is it that the exact same matrix can give two completely different sets of eigenvectors? *If there were some kind of simple unitary transformation going on, this should not affect the `np.matmul(np.matmul(C.T,F),C)` relation (mentioned above) for a real-valued matrix.* I am completely lost here and can't help but think that I am missing something very fundamental. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your matrix is symmetric, so it is guaranteed to be diagonalizable, with some `V.T @ F @ V`, with `V` an orthogonal matrix. The matrix `V` is unique up to permutation and multiplications by `-1` of the columns. (Or rotations over the subspaces corresponding to the same eigenvalues, that is not the case here since you have distinct eigen vectors).

The documentation of [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) says that the right-eigenvalues do not have a guaranteed order and that the eigenvectors have unit length. This gives us two sanity checks.

```py
        D, W = np.linalg.eig(F)
        assert(np.all(np.abs( W @ W.T - np.eye(W.shape[0])) < tol))
        assert(np.all(np.abs( F @ W - W @ np.diag(D)) < tol))
```

I checked your two matrices, and indeed `C0` is an eigenvector matrix for `F`, while `C` is not.

```py
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(C.T @ F0 @ C), plt.title('$C^T F C$')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(C0.T @ F0 @ C0), plt.title('$C_0 F C_0$')
```

[image: Congruency transform on F]

To this point it could be the case that the input matrix was different. But when we check for the orthogonality `C @ C.T ~ I` I would say that it violates the statements of eig.

```py
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(C @ C.T), plt.title('$C C^T$')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(C0 @ C0.T), plt.title('$C_0 C_0^T$')
```

[image: Ortogonality checks]

These libraries are used in many places if you can reproduce the failure this would be an important (BUG) finding.

I tested the assertions above for random matrices of dimension 2 to 10 and the two conditions above are valid within a tolerance of `1e-10`. Could be somethign with the structure of F? also tried with your F0 with a small additive noise thousands of times and it works.