# Numpy.linalg.eig is giving different results than numpy.linalg.eigh for Hermitian matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

I have one hermitian matrix (specifically, a Hamiltonian). Though phase of a singe eigenvector can be arbitrary, the quantities I am calculating is physical (I reduced the code a bit keeping just the reproducible part). eig and eigh are giving very different results.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as nlg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
def Ham(Ny, Nx, t, phi):
    h = np.zeros((Ny,Ny), dtype=complex)
    for ii in range(Ny-1):
        h[ii+1,ii] = t
    h[Ny-1,0] = t    
    h=h+np.transpose(np.conj(h))
    
    u = np.zeros((Ny,Ny), dtype=complex)
    for ii in range(Ny):
        u[ii,ii] = -t*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*phi*ii)
    u = u + 1e-10*np.eye(Ny)
    
    H = np.kron(np.eye(Nx,dtype=int),h) + np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(Nx-1), 1),u) + np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(Nx-1), -1),np.transpose(np.conj(u)))
    H[0:Ny,Ny*(Nx-1):Ny*Nx] = np.transpose(np.conj(u))    
    H[Ny*(Nx-1):Ny*Nx,0:Ny] = u                           

    x=[]; y=[]; 
    for jj in range (1,Nx+1):
        for ii in range (1,Ny+1):
            x.append(jj); y.append(ii)        
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    return H, x, y

def C_num(Nx, Ny,  E, t, phi):
    H, x, y = Ham(Ny, Nx, t, phi)
    
    ifhermitian = np.allclose(H, np.transpose(np.conj(H)), rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8)
    assert ifhermitian == True
    
    Hp = H
    V,wf = nlg.eigh(Hp)     ##Check. eig gives different result
    idx = np.argsort(np.real(V))
    wf = wf[:, idx]

    normmat = wf*np.conj(wf)
    norm = np.sqrt(np.sum(normmat, axis=0))
    wf = wf/(norm*np.sqrt(len(H)))
    
    wf = wf[:, V<=E]  ##Chose a subset of eigenvectors              
    
    V01 = wf*np.exp(1j*x)[:,None]; V12 = wf*np.exp(1j*y)[:,None]
    V23 = wf*np.exp(1j*x)[:,None]; V30 = wf*np.exp(1j*y)[:,None]
    
    wff = np.transpose(np.conj(wf))
    C01 = np.dot(wff,V01); C12 = np.dot(wff,V12); C23 = np.dot(wff,V23); C30 = np.dot(wff,V30)

    F = nlg.multi_dot([C01,C12,C23,C30])

    ifhermitian = np.allclose(F, np.transpose(np.conj(F)), rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8)
    assert ifhermitian == True

    evals, efuns = nlg.eig(F)    ##Check eig gives different result
    C = (1/(2*np.pi))*np.sum(np.angle(evals));
    
    return  C

C = C_num(16, 16, 0, 1, 1/8)
print(C)
```

Changing both nlg.eigh to nlg.eig, or even changing only the last one, giving very different results.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128956/12750353), the eigenvalue and eigenvector are not unique.

The only thing that is true is that for each eigenvalue $A v = lambda v$, the two matrices returned by `eig` and `eigh` describe those solutions, it is natural that eig inexact but approximate results.

You can see that both the solutions will triangularize your matrix in different ways

```py
H, x, y = Ham(16, 16, 1, 1./8)
D, V = nlg.eig(H)
Dh, Vh = nlg.eigh(H)
```

Then

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
plt.subplot(121);
plt.imshow(abs(np.conj(Vh.T) @ H @ Vh))
plt.title('diagonalized with eigh')
plt.subplot(122);
plt.imshow(abs(np.conj(V.T) @ H @ V))
plt.title('diagonalized with eig')
```

Plots this

[image: Different diagonalizations]

That both diagonalizations were successfull, but the eigenvalues are indifferent order.
If you sort the eigenvalues you see they match

```py
plt.plot(np.diag(np.real(np.conj(Vh.T) @ H @ Vh)))
plt.plot(np.diag(np.imag(np.conj(Vh.T) @ H @ Vh)))
plt.plot(np.sort(np.diag(np.real(np.conj(V.T) @ H @ V))))
plt.title('eigenvalues')
plt.legend(['real eigh', 'imag eigh', 'sorted real eig'], loc='upper left')
```

Since many eigenvalues are repeated, the eigenvector associated with a given eigenvalue is not unique as well, the only thing we can guarantee is that the eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue must span the same subspace.

The diagonalization test is the best in my opinion.

#### Is eigh always better than eig?

If you search for the eigenvalues in the [lapack routines](http://www.icl.utk.edu/%7Emgates3/docs/lapack.html) you will have many options. So it is I cannot discuss each possible implementation here. The common sense says that we can expect that the symmetric/hermitian routines to perform better, otherwise ther would be no reason to add one more routine that is more limited. But I never tested carefully the behavior of `eig` vs `eigh`.

To have an intuition compare the equation for tridiagonalization for symmetric matrices, and the equation for reduction of a general matrix to its Heisenberg form found [here](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node70.html).

Comment: Can it be said that it's always better to use eigh if we know that the matrix is symmetric or hermitian?